# Create hyperlink based on current URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, url-rewriting

I created a bilingual website using two databases:

www.martyregan.com/
www.martyregan.com/jp/

You can choose the language of the website using the 'Website Language' flags, but currently the links only bring you to the homepage. The paths/URLs on both sites are exactly the same, other than /jp/ directory on the Japanese site.

I'm looking for a way to alter the hyperlinks to go to the parallel page, based on the URL of the page the visitor is currently on. I figure it'd be quite simple being that the paths are identical, but not really sure where to start with my little knowledge of jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes your language is accessible as seen below.
"http://" is removed from the URL for convenience.

```
$(function(){
    var lang = 'jp';

    $('a').attr('href', function(x, url){
        var split = url.replace(/(http:)?(\/\/)?/, '').split('/');
        return split.shift() + '/' + lang + '/' + split.join('/');
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, you could put "var lang = 'jp'", inside the <head> tag. This whole snippet of code could go in the <head> tag.

Comment: I really wish I knew how to alter the damn tags on my client's CMS, Concrete5. Thank you, let me see if I can pull it off. I should set the English site's head to en too, right?

Comment: Let's say all of your links start with "www.martyregan.com"; all this does is replace your links with "www.martyregan.com/<lang>/", so if you set lang='en' for the English site, all of your links would start with: "www.martyregan.com/en/". Make sense?

Comment: That does make sense...though I don't want that to be the case. Only /jp/ for the Japanese site, like it is now. So I don't touch the head tag on the English site?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25059/discussion-between-joseph-thomas-and-slamborne)

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to get away with using the [`<base>`](http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/HTML/Elements/base) tag depending up on the browsers you need to support.  You can just set that to whatever the base is by acquiring it from the server.

If you want to use jQuery to do it, it should be fairly simple if all of your `href`s are absolute:

```
$("a").attr('href', function (_, href) {
    return $("base").attr('href') + href;
});
```

This assumes that you are using `<base>`.  If you're not you can get the path from `window.location.path`, or even some other element on the page.

*In case you are confused, the JavaScript is only required if `<base>` is not enough to work on its own*

Comment: Hmm thank you!  How would I tell this to only apply the two hyperlinks in the Website Language container?

Comment: @JosephThomas if it's only applying to *two* links, then don't use `<base>`.  You can just change your JavaScript selector: `$(".website-language-container a").attr`

Comment: Where would I use window.location.path?

Comment: @JosephThomas use it as an alternative to `$("base").attr('href')`, but it's better to just store whatever the base is supposed to be in some element on the page